# ¿Alguien sabe por qué sumar o restar con decimales no da el resultado exacto?

Tags: java, matemáticas, bigdecimal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando quiero sumar o restar con decimales no da el resultado exacto solo se acerca mucho.

También si me puede ayudar a como puedo evitar el error si no pongo ningún número pero selecciono una operación.

```
privatevoidCmboperacionActionPerformed(java.awt.event. 
     ActionEvent evt) {                                             
            lblexception.setText("");
            float res = 0;
            int i = Cmboperacion.getSelectedIndex();

 floatval1 =  Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(txtval1.getText()));

  floatval2 = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(txtval2.getText()));

        if(i == 0)res=val1+val2;
        else if(i == 1)res=val1-val2;
        else if(i == 2)res=val1*val2;
        else if(i == 3)
        {
            try
            {
                if(val2 == 0)
                {
                lblexception.setText("Error");
                }
                else
                {
                    res=val1/val2;
                }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                res=val1/val2;
            }
        }
        txtres.setText(String.valueOf(res));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es por la longitud o el tamaño del tipo float. Para evitar esto, se utiliza el tipo double, que tiene el double XD de capacidad que el float. Y eso permite sacar los decimales con mucha más exactitud. La suficiente para que este tipo de operaciones las resuelva correctamente. Ya tendrías que exigir mucha más exactitud para ver donde falla. No se cuantos decimales necesitarías para sacar el error en la operación, pero son unos cuantos. Para 10 decimales puedes estar tranquilo. No se si son muchos más o pocos más, pero para operaciones con 10 decimales puedes estar totalmente tranquilo. Así que en este ejemplo, con 1 decimal, más que de sobra.

La explicación exacta, viene en el post que te indican en el comentario a tu post. Pero la solución fácil y resumida es simplemente, usar double.

Comment: Un dato curioso es que tambien existe el dato de tipo Long, el cual puede almacenar incluso mas cantidad de decimales, pero por alguna razon el Long resulta menos preciso para hacer calculos decimales, asi que en teoria es mas preciso el double, por otro lado hay pocos casos en los que seria buena idea usar Long, por ejemplo si estas haciendo una calculadora cientifica, porque de resto, los tipos Long consumen un espacio fijo en memoria muy superior a Double e Int.

Comment: Por otro lado, también existen las clases Big... yo sólo conozco la BigInteger, que no admite decimales (supongo) pero que admite números enteros muy muy grandes (creo). Sólo la he visto por encima, no he llegado a utilizarla nunca. También podría ser interesante una clase BigDouble (no se si existe incluso ya... habría que echarle un vistazo a la API)